# Javascript for loop Uncaught TypeError from data attributes

Tags: javascript, loops, d3.js

I have a bunch of dataset's attached to some spans that I'm trying to loop through but keep getting the error: `dials.js:238 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentages' of undefined`.

My span structure is as follows:

```
<span class="dial rent"
      data-name="Rent"
      data-value="56"
      data-marker="40"
      data-min="0"
      data-max="100"
      data-percentages="0.25, 1">
    </span>
```

My JS is:

```
var dials = document.getElementsByClassName('dial');

function createGauges() {
  for (var key in dials) {
    var data = dials[key].dataset;
    var percent = data.percentages.split(',').map(Number);
    console.log(percent);
    newDial(data.name, data.value, data.marker, data.min, data.max, percent);
  }
}
```

My data output structure looks like this:

```
DOMStringMap {name: "Cost of goods", value: "23", marker: "20", min: "0", max: "100"…}
marker:"20"
max:"100"
min:"0"
name:"Cost of goods"
percentages:"0.3, 1"
value:"23"
```

I'm stumped. When I log the `percent` variable I'm getting the correct data and it's outputting to my D3 graph. But the JS is erroring out and terminates so the rest of the data won't populate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `for` loop iterates over object's keys. In your case for loop goes over `["0", "length", "item", "namedItem"]` keys for `dials`. So only valid one is `0`. Look at the keys

```
for (var key in dials){
   console.log(key); // "0", "length", "item", "namedItem"
}

function createGauges() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(dials, function(dial){
    var data = dial.dataset;
    var percent = data.percentages.split(',').map(Number);
    console.log(percent);
    newDial(data.name, data.value, data.marker, data.min, data.max, percent);
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks - it was driving me crazy.